# Denoising depth purpose?

Tags: compositing-nodes, denoise

What is the point of the "Denoising Depth" pass when using the denoise node in the compositor? When you select "Denoising Data" from the Blender view layer properties, it gives 3 additional things for the render layer. Among those 3 are Denoising Depth. However, in the denoising node in the compositor, there are only spots for image, normal, and albedo. What is the purpose of the depth pass if it won't even be used with the denoising node?

Comment: Hi :). There used to be even more denoise outputs, usually only useful for developers. I don't think there's even any documentation ;)

Comment: it seesm to me to be a anti aliased version of the depth pass. you have to add a map range to it or a normalise , but it does not work for me , it does not include the alpha of any textures
we are having a discussion over on polycount about it. The other guy got it working nice and I cannot :)
https://polycount.com/discussion/72805/blender-mega-thread#latest